# Windows displays a partition of internal drive as a removable drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-backup

I have a drive with three partitions: C: and G: and a hidden recovery partition.
Windows recognizes the G: partition as a removable drive (judging by the icon).
When I try to use the built-in backup tool, the drive is available only as a destination for the backup, not a source (backing up to a NAS).

Screenshots:

[image: Explorer]

[image: Partition manager]

[image: Windows backup 2]

[image: Windows Backup 1]

The computer was upgraded from Windows 7 Home to Windows 10 Home in order to be able to backup to a network location. The same icon appeared in Windows 7. I don't remember when the icon appeared.

Comment: StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Now it's perfect ;)

Comment: Why would you use Fat32 in the first place?

Comment: @Citizen Default option and a small drive, this is irrelevant to the problem IMO.

Comment: Really?  Perhaps you will want to understand a little more deeply the services that are supported between the various drive formats.  Once you understand how services are tied to NTFS you might understand why windows sees the drive the way it does.

Comment: @Citizen Care to elaborate? Or maybe post an answer if you know it?